# React JS - How does this function work to delete JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, event-handling, state

I hope you can help.

I can't remember where I got the the snippet of code in the **deleteHandler** function. It deletes the relevant **listdata** item from the JSON array and re-renders as expected. I just don't understand what it's doing. Is it specific React syntax? Is it rudimentary stuff that I am oblivious to?

I know the  **state.listdata.splice(id, 1);** line gets the current JSON object, but what does the arrow function do? What is being returned? I'm quite baffled by it.

Any help is much appreciated.

```js
var AppFront = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    return{
        listdata: [
          {"id":1,"name":"Push Repo","description":"Job No 8790","priority":"Important"},
          {"id":2,"name":"Second Note","description":"Job No 823790","priority":"Important"}
          ]
    }
  },
  deleteHandler: function(e,id){
    this.setState(state => {
      state.listdata.splice(id, 1);
      return {listdata: state.listdata};
    });
  },
    render: function(){
    var listDataDOM = this.state.listdata.map((item,index) => {return (<li key={item.id}>
        {item.name}
        <button onClick={()=>this.deleteHandler(item.id)}>delete</button>
      </li>)});
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>To-do List</h1>
        <ul>
        {listDataDOM}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
  });
  
  ReactDOM.render(<AppFront />,document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) About setState**

setState function in React looks something like that :

```
setState(partialState, callback)
```

Where **partialState** may be : **object , function or null.**

In your particular case you use function, which returns an object of state variables.

```
setState(function(state){ return {some:data}  })
```

and with [arrow func](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (es6) , the same will look like

```
setState(state=> { return {some:data}  })
```

in yout particular case arrow func used just for short

---

**2) About splice**

In handler, you use JS func splice() to remove element from state's array;

But it is bad practice, because it mutates the state of component.And It will cause bugs, problems and unpredictable behavior. **You shouldn't mutate your state!**

To avoid that you can copy your array through slice(), because slice returns new array.

```
      var newArray = state.listdata.slice()
      newArray.splice(index, 1);
```

---

**3) About deleteHandler and data structure**

**deleteHandler doesnt work properly**, and works only for first position.And if your data will look like that:

```
 listdata: [
          {"id":52,"name":"Push Repo","description":"Job No 8790","priority":"Important"},
          {"id":11,"name":"Second Note","description":"Job No 823790","priority":"Important"}
          ]
```

It will not work at all

**For proper result , you should change deleteHandler to this:**

```
 deleteHandler: function(e,id){
      //find index of element
      var index = this.state.listdata.findIndex(e=>e.id==id);
      //copy array
      var newAray = this.state.listdata.slice();
      //delete element by index
      newAray.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({listdata: newAray});

  },
```

and button

```
<button onClick={e=>this.deleteHandler(e,item.id)}>delete</button>
```

**> [JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/lexenicesu/1/edit?js,output)**

or you can delete by index

```
 deleteHandler: function(e,index){
      //copy array
      var newAray = this.state.listdata.slice();
      //delete element by index
      newAray.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({listdata: newAray});
  },
 <button onClick={e=>this.deleteHandler(e,index)}>delete</button>
```

**> [JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/defatafihu/1/edit?js,output)**

Comment: That worked excellently. Thank you for that. Could I trouble you to explain the this.state.listdata.findIndex(e=>e.id==id) syntax? What is findIndex and => doing in that situation?

Comment: ```findIndex``` returns index of element if callback returns true. It is the same like  ```array.findIndex(function(element){return  element.id==id } )```. When ```element.id==id``` returns true, ```findIndex``` returns index of element

Answer (score 2):

In your `AppFront` component you have a `state`

```
{
        listdata: [
          {"id":1,"name":"Push Repo","description":"Job No 8790","priority":"Important"},
          {"id":2,"name":"Second Note","description":"Job No 823790","priority":"Important"}
        ]
    }
```

It represents initial data in your component. Every time you change `state`, your component gets rerendered.

You can change `state` by calling component's [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) method

In `deleteHandler`

```
deleteHandler: function(e,id){
    this.setState(state => {
      // state.listdata - array of initial values,
      state.listdata.splice(id, 1);
      return {listdata: state.listdata}; // returns a new state
    });
  }
```

`state.listdata.splice(id, 1)` // removes an element with index == id from the array. You should not confuse `listdata` `item.id` and item `index`. In order for your code to work correctly you need to pass `index` in you `deleteHandler`.

```
<button onClick={()=>this.deleteHandler(index)}>delete</button>
```

Another thing is that you call `deleteHandler` only with one argument -  item `index` so in your definition it should be

```
  deleteHandler: function(index){
    this.setState(state => {
      // state.listdata - array of initial values,
      state.listdata.splice(index, 1);
      return {listdata: state.listdata}; // returns a new state
    });
  }
```

In your `render` method you iterate through `this.state.listdata` and return `React.DOM` nodes for each.

When you update component's `state` it gets rerendered and you see that item was deleted.

This code is written in [es2015](https://css-tricks.com/lets-learn-es2015/) so if it's new to you, it's better to start from reading something about new syntaxis.

Comment: Thanks for that. Awesome explanation. Why do we not use e or item.id?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: I was using the item.id to get the position of the object in the array. I guess e is redundant.

Comment: You can not use item.id to get position of item in array. You can do it by index. Or use `state.listdata.find(item => item.id === id);`

Answer (score 1):

`state.listdata.splice(id, 1)` deletes 1 element  with the index equal to `id` from `listdata` array. For example if `id` equals to 0, then, after applying `state.listdata.splice(id, 1)`, `state.listdata` will become:

```
listdata: [          
      {"id":2,"name":"Second Note","description":"Job No 823790","priority":"Important"}
      ]
```

And exactly this array will be returned by this arrow functions.

Keeping in mind, that `splice` method receives index as first argument, but you pass `id` property there, most probably you should change this code:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.deleteHandler(item.id)}>delete</button>
```

To:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.deleteHandler(index)}>delete</button>
```